# Communication issue between PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a page generated from PHP like this:

```
<?php
    //In my original code, this is retrieved from databas..
    $users = array(
        array('id'=>1, 'login'=>'login1', 'email'=>'email1')
    );  
    foreach($users as $user){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$user['login'].'</td><td>'.$user['email'].'</td><td><button class="button-delete">Delete</button></td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

Then, in front side I have this script:

```
$('.button-delete').click(function(){
    var id=0;
    alert(id);
});
```

My aim is to make Delete button perform an ajax call to delete the user. Till now I didn't got there yet, my problem is how to get the user ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send the id within the button **[data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** and easily get it after.

```
<?php
    //In my original code, this is retrieved from databas..
    $users = array(
        array('id'=>1, 'login'=>'login1', 'email'=>'email1')
    );  
    foreach($users as $user){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$user['login'].'</td><td>'.$user['email'].'</td><td><button class="button-delete" data-id="'.$user['id'].'">Delete</button></td></tr>';
    }
?>

$('.button-delete').click(function(){
    var id=$(this).data('id');
    alert(id);
});
```

Comment: Nice use of the data attribute feature; it's much better than using inline `onclick` attributes or binding new functions for each button.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do something like this:

```
<?php
    //note the change from button tag to anchor tag
    $users = array(
        array('id'=>1, 'login'=>'login1', 'email'=>'email1')
    );  
    foreach($users as $user){
        echo '<tr><td>'.$user['login'].'</td><td>'.$user['email'].'</td><td><a href="/link/to/delete/id/'.$user['id'].'/" class="button-delete">Delete</a></td></tr>';
    }
?>
```

And then in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button-delete').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        //Make an AJAX request to the delete script using the href attribute as url
        $.get($this.attr('href'), function(response) {
            //Inside your php script echo out 1 if the delete was successful.
            if(response) {
                //remove the parent row
                $this.parents('tr').fadeOut(1000, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I haven't tested the code but it should work. Have in mind that there are loads of ways to do this and this is my preferred way. **My point is that you don't necessarily need the id as an individual variable.**